# Postman - Setting a cookie from a global variable with "Tests" code

Tags: postman

What i want to do is to take a cookie value I've received after a "GET" message , set it's value as a global variable, then set it as a session cookie for a specific host, and later on use it in other requests.

Currently i'm doing this manually via this menu:

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Is there any real solution that you have found? One that allows you to use `test` script and set a cookie?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is in the `Test` on response store the value you want to use in a global variable `postman.setGlobalVariable('key', value)` then in the request you want to use it as a cookie, pass along the value in the header as a cookie where:

`Cookie` | `cookieName={{key}}`

Check out the MZN docs on [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) to see how to send multiple cookies in one header.

Comment: `pm.globals.set("key", value)`

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is well documented on the POSTMAN site. You require the interceptor plugin and the instructions to use it are here:

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/interceptor_cookies

Comment: actually is you scroll down the page you'll see instructions how to do it programmatically

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov, where exactly?? Is it removed now?